# Adjusting the positioning of the subnav dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown, styling

New here and kind of new to coding - I've dabbled but that's it. It's been 6 years since I last touched any form of code.

I'm trying to replicate a website for practice and I've got a nav and a dropdown subnav. The issue  I'm having is trying to get the sub nav dropdown to go underneath the link it's meant for. I'll attach examples and my code. Any help is appreciated. Please feel free to correct anything you see fit - I've just started again and would rather know the correct way other than continue with any bad practices. I can also do what I want with the sub nav but this is with the left and right elements with a negative px which I don't want to do.

**How it's meant to look**:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdCec.png)

**How I've got it so far**: 
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxXTY.png)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWKn6.png)

I'm trying to get the arrow to link up as shown as well. Does anyone also know how to amend with width of that properly?

My html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head> 
             <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Arnold Clark &vert; New & Used Cars</title> 

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


        </head> 
            <body>

                <div id="ac-header">
                        <a href="#"><img id="ac-logo" src="ac.png" alt="Arnold Clark logo" /></a>
                    <div id="nav">
                        <span>Find a car</span>
                            <div id="nav-Dropdown">
                                <p>
                                    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;">We sell</div>
                                </p>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Used cars</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">New cars</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Nearly new cars</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Car finance</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Vans</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Motability</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="nav">
                        <span class="pointer">Find a van</span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="nav">
                        <span class="pointer">Find a dealer</span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="nav">
                        <span class="pointer">Rental</span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="nav">
                        <span class="pointer">Servicing</span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="nav">
                        <span class="pointer">Other</span>
                            <div id="nav-Dropdown">
                                <ul>
                                    <div style="font-weight: bold;">
                                        <li>About Arnold Clark</li>
                                    </div>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div id="wrapper">

                    Content goes in here. 

                </div>
            </body>
    </html>
```

My CSS:

```
    body {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    font-family: "Gotham A", "Gotham B", "Gotham", "Montserrat", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    /* Removed the white space on either side of the container */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


#wrapper { 
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: 15px;
}

#ac-header {
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: #2d3737;
    height: 63px;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #ffde00; 
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

}

#ac-logo {
    object-fit: contain; 
    width: 285px;
    height: 43px;
    padding-left: 41px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

#nav {
    position: relative;
    display:  inline-block;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 500px;
    top: 15px;
}

#nav > span {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#nav > span:hover {
    color: #ffde00;
    background-color: #282e2e;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;


}

#nav > #nav-Dropdown {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 590px;
    top: 100px;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
}

#nav > #nav-Dropdown > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#nav > #nav-Dropdown > ul > li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}

#nav > #nav-Dropdown > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;

}

#nav:hover #nav-Dropdown {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after. You want to change the `top` value for the `ul` that appears when `#nav` is `:hover`

Just change your `50px` to `58px` and it should be aligned like you intent. :)

```
#nav:hover #nav-Dropdown {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    top: 58px;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    font-family: "Gotham A", "Gotham B", "Gotham", "Montserrat", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    /* Removed the white space on either side of the container */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


#wrapper { 
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: 15px;
}

#ac-header {
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: #2d3737;
    height: 63px;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #ffde00; 
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

}

#ac-logo {
    object-fit: contain; 
    width: 285px;
    height: 43px;
    padding-left: 41px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

#nav {
    position: relative;
    display:  inline-block;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 500px;
    top: 15px;
}

#nav > span {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#nav > span:hover {
    color: #ffde00;
    background-color: #282e2e;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;


}

#nav-Dropdown {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 590px;
    top: 100px;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
}

#nav #nav-Dropdown ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0; 
    font-size: 14px;
}

#nav > #nav-Dropdown > ul > li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}

#nav > #nav-Dropdown > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;

}

#nav:hover #nav-Dropdown {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    top: 58px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ac-header">
                        <a href="#"><img id="ac-logo" src="ac.png" alt="Arnold Clark logo" /></a>
                    <div id="nav">
                        <span>Find a car</span>
                            <div id="nav-Dropdown">
                                <p>
                                    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;">We sell</div>
                                </p>
                                <ul class="subDropdown">
                                    <li><a href="#">Used cars</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">New cars</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Nearly new cars</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Car finance</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Vans</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Motability</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="nav">
                        <span class="pointer">Find a van</span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="nav">
                        <span class="pointer">Find a dealer</span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="nav">
                        <span class="pointer">Rental</span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="nav">
                        <span class="pointer">Servicing</span>
                    </div>

                    <div id="nav">
                        <span class="pointer">Other</span>
                            <div id="nav-Dropdown">
                                <ul>
                                    <div style="font-weight: bold;">
                                        <li>About Arnold Clark</li>
                                    </div>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div id="wrapper">

                    Content goes in here. 

                </div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input. Very much appreciated. 
What do you mean by "I think this is what you're after. You want to change the top value for the ul that appears when #nav is :hover"

Comment: You're styling the child dropdown on the `#nav` element while it is being **hovered**. That targets the dropdown you are trying to style. :)

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks again. Have I understood you correctly? I've changed my code to this: 

#nav > #nav-Dropdown {
 display: none;
}

#nav:hover #nav-Dropdown {
 background-color: #fff;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 590px;
 top: 100px;
 top: 58px;
 padding: 12px 16px;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
 -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
 border: 0px solid #000000;

Comment: The code block that I added above the snippet is what you need to replace.

Comment: You can also just copy the entire CSS of the snippet and paste into your project if you want as well.

Comment: Hi Joel,
Thanks I changed my code and it's neater. It's still not allowing me to position my drop down menu to show like the original image. For example, "Find a car" has a dropdown menu directly underneath when hovered over, and the arrow on the dropdown is pointing to the "Find a car" text. Is there anyway to align it like so?

Comment: Can you post pictures on your question for me to look at?

Comment: Hi Joel, please click on the example links in original post for the images, thank you

Answer (score 0):

So what you will want to do is have a li element that has a child element that wraps the links within it for its

```js
var dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdownParent');

dropdown.onclick = function() {
  var target = document.getElementById(this.dataset.droptarget)
  target.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
ul {
display: flex;
list-style: none;
justify-content: space-around;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown #dropdownOne {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 30px;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.dropdown #dropdownOne.active {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdownParent" href="#" data-droptarget="dropdownOne">Item 3</a>
    <div id="dropdownOne">
      <a href="#">Dropdown Item</a>
      <a href="#">Dropdown Item</a>
      <a href="#">Dropdown Item</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

dropdown menu. See code.